# Index out of bound exception console app

Tags: c#

What i don't understand is that line :

```
 Class exmp
 {
    Static void Main(String userinput)
    {
       Int input = int.parse(userinput[0]);
    }
 }
```

Has apparantely no method to take an argument, so this might be the reason of execption
I'm newbie, help

Comment: You need to use `Int input = int.parse(userinput)`, userinput is not an array

Comment: In C#, `String` can be accessed as an array of `Char`s.

Comment: That is true. `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`

Comment: But problem is that i throws error before taking any input , does it even take input at runtime ?

Answer (score 3):

`userinput[0]` is the first char of the string. So for an empty string there is no first char, and hence: `Index out of bounds`

If you want to safeguard against this you could do the following:

```
 Class exmp
 {
    Static void Main(String userinput)
    {
      Int input = 0;
      if( userinput.length > 0 )
      {
        int.TryParse(userinput[0], out input);
      }
    }
 }
```

This sets `input` as `0` if an empty string is passed in.

So for the input `'532632fergerg'` `input` will be `'5'`
For the input `'fwehgwerhwh'` it will blow up since `'f'` is not a string. In that case you would probably want to use `TryParse` instead of `Parse`.

**EDIT**
Updated my code to use TryParse since that is much more reliable, especially when working with user input that you have no clue what is.

Comment: I would go with TryParse() over Parse() anytime to keep the code as solid as possible.

Comment: @scheien - Agreed. Made my example more solid now.

Comment: But problem is that i throws error before taking any input , does it even take input at runtime ?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userinput))
    int input = int.parse(userinput[0]);
```

this is if you want to parse the first char (as per your code)

if you want the entire string parsed change it to

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userinput))
    int input = int.parse(userinput);
```

This will still throw can execption though if the string cannot be parsed. Look into using [`Int32.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

```
int input;
if(Int32.TryParse(userinput, out input))
{
  //Do Work
}
```

Comment: First example is of you want to parse the first char only.

Comment: But problem is that i throws error before taking any input , does it even take input at runtime ?